# Symfony rabbitmq messenger with remote ssh not returning response

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, symfony5

I have made small integration with rabbitmq, and im getting problems when i need to return value from my messengerHandler.

From the start:

1. I have in my API endpoint, where i pass: username,ip,password and command which later i pass them via `bus->dispatch`:

```php
namespace App\Controller\ApiFunctions;

use App\Message\SshShellQueue;
use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\HandledStamp;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class RabbitSshQueuingCalls extends AbstractController
{
  /**
   * @Route("/api/RabbitSsh",name="apiRabbitSsh")
   * @param MessageBusInterface $bus
   */
  function sendCommand(Request $request, MessageBusInterface $bus)
  {
      $ip = $request->get('ip');
      $username = $request->get('username');
      $password = $request->get('password');
      $command = $request->get('command');
      $strCommand = strval($command);
      $returnValue = $bus->dispatch(new SshShellQueue($strCommand,$password,$username,$ip));
      $handledStamp  = $returnValue->last(HandledStamp::class);

      return $this->json([
          'msg' => 'command has been queued',
          'status'=>$handledStamp //<-here i want to pass result of command that i passed
      ]);
  }
}
```

and the dispatch is pushing data here, to the messageHandler and are processed via rabbitmq:

```php
namespace App\Message\MessageHandler;
use App\Message\SshShellQueue;

use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Attribute\AsMessageHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;


class SshShellQueueHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __invoke(SshShellQueue $queue){
        $ip = $queue->getIp();
        $ssh = new SSH2($ip);
        if (!$ssh->login($queue->getUsername(), $queue->getPassword())) {
            dump('Login Failed');
        }
        $variable = ($ssh->exec($queue->getContent()));
        var_dump($variable);
    }
```

and after ill pass correct credentials to my server the command that i pass is working, lets say i pass command: `pwd`

and i can see result in terminal when my `messenger:consume` is working
but i want to lets say pass it back to the my endpoint and i want to return it via `return $this->json`

Comment: Messenger is asynchronous in nature (except if you use the `sync` transport), the handler executes in another process so you cannot return the output to the controller, once the transport acknowledges the message the controller continues executing and `kernel.terminate` is called.

Comment: So the problem might not be the messenger but maybe SSH2 library im using? Or is there any way to return anything from handler?

Comment: No, _I don't think so_; even when using the `sync` transport but you are free to double check. _Maybe_ you can just use the [`Process` component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) but I'd say it's more likely than not that you run into performance issues. Otherwise you could look into Mercure / Vulcain for an async solution, but I wouldn't dare to try to answer a complete solution in a comment. Best of luck, though.

Comment: Well i have Mercure integration also, but ill see what i can do tomorrow, thanks anyway for help!

Comment: I think the same @msg, the final result of message handler must be returned by Mercure.

Comment: Turns out it's possible and [even documented](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger/handler_results.html) to return from a handler, as long as it is handled synchronously and by one and one handler only. Still, you could hit performance issues, but you can try and measure first.